# dualboot macbook pro retina 2013

Tags: dual-boot, macbook, refind

I guys,

can some one please tell me or give a recipt, about, how to do a dual boot of elementary OS and macbook pro retina 2013, OSX Capitan? is necessary reFInd? how do I do that?

I search on a lot of web pages and I find sevel task ads steps, but no one do really.. sometimes work and others not :(.
I found that depends of several thing like version of OSX, year of laptop, drivers, SIP restriction on Capitan OSX over REFIND, and so on.

thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I'm actually doing this exact thing! rEFInd can be useful, but it is by no means required. Do you have any other OSs installed too, or just Mac? (In particular, you have to be careful if you have Windows with Boot Camp.)